# Anonymity on the Web 101

Tags: anonymity

nice to meet you all! I'm newbie on this stack. Sorry if I did anything idiot :)

Well, I'm very curious about browsing on the web completly anonymous. I would like to hide the websites, e-mails, messengers, downloads and most of the basic services from my ISP provider and the NSA/CSA/NORAD/USGOV/BRGOV etc etc etc.

There's an 101 about that somewhere? what softwares to use, what internet services restrict logs and things like that?

Thank you all for helping, sorry my poor english and good day to evebody!

Comment: Also this questions: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13416/whats-the-best-way-to-make-my-internet-traffic-anonymous  and a search of the site for "anonymous browsing" brings up a long list of existing related questions.

Comment: An **evil** solution, probably not covered in the innocent answers of the earlier versions of this question, is: *Steal someone's identity and pretend to be them online.* As true anonymity is extremely hard, while identity theft in this day and age is sickeningly common.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide that stuff from your ISP check out the different VPN providers out there like [PrivateInterNetAccess](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/) or [BTGuard](http://btguard.com/). There's a ton of others out there too. It's not that expensive and you get an encrypted tunnel to the VPN provider. Now you just have to trust the VPN provider :)

Another thing you can check out is [tailsOS](https://tails.boum.org/). This is a virtual machine that will route all of your traffic through the [tor](https://www.torproject.org/) network. On the tor network you don't really want to use any of your personal accounts because anyone can setup an end node and anyone can sniff on that end node.

The NSA and the other TLA's out there already have access to google, facebook and god knows what else so if you send email through google they will have it no matter how many VPN's you use.